# How to stretch left and right edges of image equally in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview

I want my image to stretch both left and right edges equally using the below code. But it only stretched to the right. How to get it stretch both left and right edges equally?

```
let originalImage = UIImage(named: "bg_bottom")!
let inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 188, 124, 188)
let strechedImage = originalImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: inset)
imageView.image = strechedImage
```

Original image (192x128):
[image: Original image (192x128)]

What I want: [image: What I want]

What I get: [image: What I get]

Comment: Please post code of `resizableImage(withCapInsets: inset)`.

Comment: @SagarChauhan that is a function of `UIImage`

Comment: That function doesn't do what you want; it stretches the center and leaves the caps (ends) intact.

Comment: @SagarChauhan It's already posted in the question.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's why I'm asking for how.

Comment: The answers in the duplicate will help you.  There is a "how" in both Objective C and Swift.